# How to test if a string contains gibberish?

Tags: php, validation, markov-chains

I am making a registering form and because some will enter gibberish in the Secret Answer's input (I do that myself), I would like to test that value to see if it's likely to be a good answer. I have a function that generates Markov Chains (at bottom) but don't know how to test a string against that chains' Array to detect the % accuracy of the answer.

How to test if a string contains gibberish?

```
function generateCaptchaTextMarkov($length) {
    $transitionMatrix = array(
    0.0001, 0.0218, 0.0528, 0.1184, 0.1189, 0.1277, 0.1450, 0.1458, 0.1914, 0.1915, 0.2028, 0.2792, 0.3131, 0.5293, 0.5304, 0.5448, 0.5448, 0.6397, 0.7581, 0.9047, 0.9185, 0.9502, 0.9600, 0.9601, 0.9982, 1.0000, 
    0.0893, 0.0950, 0.0950, 0.0950, 0.4471, 0.4471, 0.4471, 0.4471, 0.4784, 0.4821, 0.4821, 0.6075, 0.6078, 0.6078, 0.7300, 0.7300, 0.7300, 0.7979, 0.8220, 0.8296, 0.9342, 0.9348, 0.9351, 0.9351, 1.0000, 1.0000, 
    0.1313, 0.1317, 0.1433, 0.1433, 0.3264, 0.3264, 0.3264, 0.4887, 0.5454, 0.5454, 0.5946, 0.6255, 0.6255, 0.6255, 0.8022, 0.8022, 0.8035, 0.8720, 0.8753, 0.9545, 0.9928, 0.9928, 0.9928, 0.9928, 1.0000, 1.0000, 
    0.0542, 0.0587, 0.0590, 0.0840, 0.3725, 0.3837, 0.3879, 0.3887, 0.5203, 0.5208, 0.5211, 0.5390, 0.5435, 0.5550, 0.8183, 0.8191, 0.8191, 0.8759, 0.9376, 0.9400, 0.9629, 0.9648, 0.9664, 0.9664, 1.0000, 1.0000, 
    0.0860, 0.0877, 0.1111, 0.2533, 0.3017, 0.3125, 0.3183, 0.3211, 0.3350, 0.3355, 0.3378, 0.4042, 0.4381, 0.5655, 0.5727, 0.5842, 0.5852, 0.7817, 0.8718, 0.9191, 0.9201, 0.9530, 0.9652, 0.9792, 0.9998, 1.0000, 
    0.1033, 0.1037, 0.1050, 0.1057, 0.2916, 0.3321, 0.3324, 0.3324, 0.4337, 0.4337, 0.4337, 0.4912, 0.4912, 0.4912, 0.7237, 0.7274, 0.7274, 0.8545, 0.8569, 0.9150, 0.9986, 0.9986, 0.9990, 0.9990, 1.0000, 1.0000, 
    0.1014, 0.1017, 0.1024, 0.1028, 0.2725, 0.2729, 0.2855, 0.4981, 0.5770, 0.5770, 0.5770, 0.6184, 0.6191, 0.6384, 0.7783, 0.7797, 0.7797, 0.9249, 0.9663, 0.9688, 0.9923, 0.9923, 0.9937, 0.9937, 1.0000, 1.0000, 
    0.2577, 0.2579, 0.2580, 0.2581, 0.6967, 0.6970, 0.6970, 0.6970, 0.8648, 0.8648, 0.8650, 0.8661, 0.8667, 0.8670, 0.9397, 0.9397, 0.9397, 0.9509, 0.9533, 0.9855, 0.9926, 0.9926, 0.9929, 0.9929, 1.0000, 1.0000, 
    0.0324, 0.0478, 0.0870, 0.1267, 0.1585, 0.1908, 0.2182, 0.2183, 0.2193, 0.2193, 0.2309, 0.2859, 0.3426, 0.6110, 0.6501, 0.6579, 0.6583, 0.6923, 0.8211, 0.9764, 0.9781, 0.9948, 0.9949, 0.9965, 0.9965, 1.0000, 
    0.1276, 0.1276, 0.1276, 0.1276, 0.4286, 0.4286, 0.4286, 0.4286, 0.4337, 0.4337, 0.4337, 0.4337, 0.4337, 0.4337, 0.6684, 0.6684, 0.6684, 0.6684, 0.6684, 0.6684, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 
    0.0033, 0.0059, 0.0100, 0.0109, 0.5401, 0.5443, 0.5477, 0.5485, 0.7149, 0.7149, 0.7149, 0.7316, 0.7333, 0.9247, 0.9264, 0.9273, 0.9273, 0.9289, 0.9791, 0.9816, 0.9824, 0.9824, 0.9833, 0.9833, 1.0000, 1.0000, 
    0.0850, 0.0865, 0.0874, 0.1753, 0.3439, 0.3725, 0.3744, 0.3746, 0.5083, 0.5083, 0.5192, 0.6784, 0.6840, 0.6848, 0.8088, 0.8128, 0.8128, 0.8147, 0.8326, 0.8511, 0.8743, 0.8817, 0.9054, 0.9054, 1.0000, 1.0000, 
    0.1562, 0.1760, 0.1774, 0.1776, 0.5513, 0.5517, 0.5517, 0.5520, 0.6352, 0.6352, 0.6352, 0.6369, 0.6486, 0.6499, 0.7717, 0.8230, 0.8230, 0.8337, 0.8697, 0.8703, 0.9376, 0.9376, 0.9378, 0.9378, 1.0000, 1.0000, 
    0.0255, 0.0265, 0.0682, 0.2986, 0.4139, 0.4204, 0.6002, 0.6009, 0.6351, 0.6360, 0.6507, 0.6672, 0.6679, 0.6786, 0.7718, 0.7723, 0.7732, 0.7873, 0.8364, 0.9715, 0.9753, 0.9797, 0.9803, 0.9804, 0.9997, 1.0000, 
    0.0050, 0.0089, 0.0183, 0.0379, 0.0410, 0.1451, 0.1494, 0.1514, 0.1654, 0.1656, 0.1866, 0.2171, 0.2821, 0.4272, 0.4761, 0.4926, 0.4927, 0.6434, 0.6722, 0.7195, 0.9126, 0.9332, 0.9913, 0.9925, 0.9999, 1.0000, 
    0.1596, 0.1688, 0.1688, 0.1688, 0.3799, 0.3799, 0.3799, 0.4011, 0.4827, 0.4827, 0.4833, 0.6081, 0.6087, 0.6090, 0.7353, 0.7953, 0.7953, 0.8804, 0.9181, 0.9584, 0.9952, 0.9952, 0.9952, 0.9952, 1.0000, 1.0000, 
    0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 
    0.0902, 0.0938, 0.1003, 0.1555, 0.4505, 0.4606, 0.4705, 0.4740, 0.5928, 0.5928, 0.6018, 0.6201, 0.6402, 0.6605, 0.7619, 0.7666, 0.7671, 0.8125, 0.8645, 0.9029, 0.9226, 0.9298, 0.9319, 0.9319, 0.9996, 1.0000, 
    0.0584, 0.0598, 0.0903, 0.0912, 0.2850, 0.2870, 0.2883, 0.3902, 0.5057, 0.5058, 0.5165, 0.5271, 0.5400, 0.5447, 0.6525, 0.6762, 0.6792, 0.6792, 0.7512, 0.9370, 0.9843, 0.9851, 0.9953, 0.9953, 0.9999, 1.0000, 
    0.0416, 0.0419, 0.0466, 0.0467, 0.1673, 0.1696, 0.1697, 0.6314, 0.7003, 0.7003, 0.7003, 0.7142, 0.7150, 0.7160, 0.8626, 0.8626, 0.8627, 0.9023, 0.9255, 0.9498, 0.9746, 0.9746, 0.9812, 0.9812, 0.9998, 1.0000, 
    0.0141, 0.0308, 0.0668, 0.0877, 0.1241, 0.1282, 0.1874, 0.1874, 0.2191, 0.2192, 0.2210, 0.3626, 0.3794, 0.4618, 0.4632, 0.5097, 0.5097, 0.6957, 0.8373, 0.9949, 0.9949, 0.9961, 0.9963, 0.9982, 0.9984, 1.0000, 
    0.0740, 0.0740, 0.0740, 0.0740, 0.8423, 0.8423, 0.8423, 0.8423, 0.9486, 0.9486, 0.9486, 0.9486, 0.9486, 0.9491, 0.9836, 0.9836, 0.9836, 0.9849, 0.9849, 0.9849, 0.9907, 0.9907, 0.9907, 0.9907, 1.0000, 1.0000, 
    0.2785, 0.2789, 0.2795, 0.2823, 0.4088, 0.4118, 0.4118, 0.6070, 0.7774, 0.7774, 0.7782, 0.7840, 0.7840, 0.8334, 0.9704, 0.9704, 0.9704, 0.9861, 0.9996, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000, 
    0.0741, 0.0741, 0.1963, 0.1963, 0.2519, 0.2741, 0.2741, 0.3333, 0.4000, 0.4000, 0.4000, 0.4000, 0.4000, 0.4000, 0.4037, 0.6741, 0.7667, 0.7667, 0.7667, 0.9667, 0.9963, 0.9963, 0.9963, 0.9963, 1.0000, 1.0000, 
    0.0082, 0.0130, 0.0208, 0.0225, 0.1587, 0.1608, 0.1613, 0.1686, 0.2028, 0.2028, 0.2032, 0.2322, 0.2391, 0.2417, 0.8232, 0.8314, 0.8314, 0.8409, 0.9529, 0.9965, 0.9965, 0.9965, 0.9991, 0.9996, 1.0000, 1.0000, 
    0.0678, 0.0678, 0.0763, 0.0763, 0.7373, 0.7373, 0.7373, 0.7458, 0.8729, 0.8729, 0.8729, 0.8814, 0.8814, 0.8814, 0.9237, 0.9237, 0.9237, 0.9237, 0.9237, 0.9407, 0.9492, 0.9492, 0.9492, 0.9492, 0.9492, 1.0000
    );

    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $captchaText = '';
    $char = rand(0, 25);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $captchaText .= chr($char + 65 + 32);

        // Look up next char in transition matrix
        $next = rand(0, 10000) / 10000;
        for ($j = 0; $j < 26; $j++) {
            if ($next < $transitionMatrix[$char * 26 + $j]) {
                $char = $j;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    return $captchaText;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're implementing something like http://www.captcha.net/? If the secret answer will always be a dictionary word, why not just check against a dictionary?

Comment: @Tom, The secret answers could contains multiple words. But how fast is comparing the information against a dictionary versus using (if only I knew how to) a Markov Chain's algorithm ?

Comment: God help me if the place of my birth was Llanfairpwllgwyngyll, Wales.

Comment: Please don't use a secret answer/question. If you don't use it, why should others do? IMO these question/answer things are worse than captchas.

Comment: @DrColossos, I totally agree with you but explain this to a customer if he sees it's still widely used.

Comment: Don't. Many people considder these secret questions a huge security risk and will purposefully enter nonsense as it can be used to get access to your account simply by checking out your facebook page "Oh, he grew up in Llanfairpwllgwyngyll? Great, I have his answer." That's basically how sarah palin's email was 'hacked.' Don't do this to me!

Comment: gibberish: meaningless or unintelligible talk or writing. The scope is so wide as to include all languages, trades, and cultures? I doubt it can be done. While 'kj1,dfa771' may be "gibberish" to you, it is, in fact, my mother's maiden name.

Comment: If your users want to put in junk, they will. They won't be stopped. Why not just allow password recovery via email?

Answer (score 5):

Though the following technique would not be very accurate, **in my opinion**, you could gather a set of english rules and compare against them.

The only way I see around this is (and by all means not a perfect solution) a system that raises certain flags when something is suspicious.

English (and every language) has certain particularities and if you see that they are not met, this could be and indication of gibberish.

I "would" make a system that adds points when a criteria is met, and after some points, the user would get a warning.

Some examples:

**Consecutive consonants:**

- 3 consonants in a row => 5 points (many exeptions like "chrome")
- 4 consonants in a row => 15 points
- 5 consonants in a row => 30 points
- 6 consonants in a row => 60 points (can't think of many words)

(The points system is of course an example!)

The same would apply with **consecutive vowels**.

**Special characters:**

This should add some points if they appear and are not native to the site's language.

(|#¢∞¬÷“≠) etc

As they could be typos because of gibberish.

**Length:**

After a certain length, every letter should start adding points. A 28 character word is not as probable as a 7 letter one.

This are the ones in the top of my mind of course this is not an exact (or even good) science.

Also you could try some **"Common gibberish"**:

You could search for combinations like:

qwerty
asdfg
zxcvb
uiop
or what ever.

Of course this last one is completely random and will probably cover **very few** cases, but you could do as much as you want.

So this is the best I could come up with now, I'm sure there are lot more English grammar rules and particularities that you could use to your advantage, but this will only give you a certain probability, so I wouldn't make your rules compulsory by all means!! in any case something like a warning: *"If you put a completely random answer you might not remember it later"*.

This is a very complex subject, but very interesting question IMO, my answer of course only covers a very little part that would avoid some answers like: "ksfjdngssjk", although it would be very easy to set up a system like this with PHP and try it out.

Good luck!!

Comment: It's abviously like a password strength checker but with grammar check algorithm. Nice one.

Answer (score 5):

Make the user retype the secret answer one more time (as when you set new passwords). Also hide the typed-in-text as with passwords [input type = "password"]. This will make it impossible for them to copy the answer and paste in the retype field. So their best way out is to use a secret answer that makes sense to them.

I don't think any algorithmic way of checking for gibberish would be very accurate, because 'gibberish' is relative :)