# How to validate text as not gibberish in PHP?

Tags: php, string, validation

What is the best way to validate a string as not gibberish using PHP?

For example, if I get a string input from a user that must be at least 250 characters long, how can I tell whether they entered legitimate text (e.g. real words) or just gibberish to comply with the minimum characters (e.g. asdlfkjefksjlfkjldskfjelkef)?

I've thought about counting the number of words as one option, but the user could still space out their gibberish (e.g. asdlf kjef ksjlf kjl dskfje lkef), so it needs another kind of check on top of that.

Is there any way to check that at least half of a string contains real dictionary words, or something to that effect?

What is the best solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: That sort of depends on the expected natural language - it could be that the "gibberish" is just "not the language you were expecting". Other than that, the dictionary approach sounds workable.

Comment: This is a tricky problem, although there's a PHP implementation of Markov chains here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672822/how-to-test-if-a-string-contains-gibberish-in-php

Comment: what type of data is it that you're trying to validate? how much text would be entered? Is it a paragraph or an essay?

Comment: Regarding the above questions, the language would be English and the length would be about a paragraph.  Based on that, any other ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that properly because [Colorless green ideas sleep furiously](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously).

Comment: Well, it depends what are the criteria for "not gibberish" is - is grammatical correctness enough?

Comment: @Piskvor The OP didn't say. I'm assuming "gibberish" to extent to the semantic level and then it's difficult, even though Markov chains could give you a probability rating. I just dont see how implementing that for a webapp justifies the effort. I probably could replace the "properly" to "within reasonable effort".

Comment: Unhelpful answer, the question is NOT about detecting semantically correct sentences.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)

Answer (score 1):

You can walk through your dictionary and delete all dictionary words from user input and then check the length of the rest

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [Markov Chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chains). Simply put the idea is this algorithm determines whether sequences of characters look like they belong together. It won't necessarily tell you it's not gibberish, but it should catch out things like "ksjhglah etc".

See [Markov text generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chains#Markov_text_generators)